# C# Ftp DownloadFiles Progress

Tags: c#, progress

I downloaded ftp.dll and I'm using it. I used that code :

```
ftp.DownloadFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.update_ver,
Application.StartupPath,
new RemoteSearchOptions("*.*", true));
```

But I want use progress bar which shows progress of download.

There is link for download : http://www.limilabs.com/ftp

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have solved your problem. Here are a few steps to fix it:

**STEP 1:**
Add Background Worker.

**STEP 2:**
Set WorkerReportsProgress to True at Properties.

**STEP 3:**
Add `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` to form load.

**STEP 4:**
Double Click Background Worker

**STEP 5:**
Add your codes here...
Add this code to end of your code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
     backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
     // You can remove Sleeep. I added because my download is realy fast.
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

**STEP 6:**
Click Events at Properties.

**STEP 7:**
Double click Progress Changed

**STEP 8:**
Add `Statusbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;`

**STEP 9:**
Double click RunWorkerCompleted

**STEP 10:**
Add your code for finished downloaded.

I hope this will help to everyone.